# How do I suppress additional content in freemarker template file?

Tags: java, freemarker, javalite, activeweb

My company uses java lite (active web) and freemarker templates for display in some legacy web pages. I wrote an active web AppController which is forwarding to an ftl display file (freemarker template) and I'm able to see the 'hello world' content. However somehow the page is also getting our standard web site header and footer content and I have no idea how to suppress that or where to look. Is there some global configuration for javalite that says to include headers and footers for all pages and can it be supressed?

```
public class MfaController extends AppController {
    @GET
    public void registration()  {
        //does nothing
    }
}
```

registration.ftl:

```
<html>
<body>hello world</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaLite is not using configuration files. Instead it uses conventions. What you observe is a default behavior.
The default layout located in

```
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/layouts/default_layout.ftl
```

is applied to all web pages, unless you tell the framework you do not need it.

If you do not want a layout, you can turn it off by overriding a `getLayout()` method:

```java
public class MfaController extends AppController {

    public void registration()  {
        //does nothing
    }
    public String getLayout(){
        return null;
    }
}
```

A alternative  solution will look like this:

```java
public class MfaController extends AppController {
    public void registration()  {
         render().noLayout();
    }
}
```

Also, the `@GET` annotation is redundant, all actions are GET by default if public.

Here is the docs:
https://javalite.io/views#default-layout

Comment: thanks that did the trick I had no idea where to start without your assistance.

Comment: Documentation is not a bad place to start :), glad it worked for you.